# Custom filter using app.filter getting called before model is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have been trying to add my custom filter to filter out the main list based on locales. To get the main list, I am putting an ajax call. While trying to debug, it looks like `app.filter` seems to execute before the ajax provides the response. Below is the error i am getting:

> angular.js:15712TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at messageSelectionCtrl.js:57
>       at fn (eval at  (angular.js:14059), :4:360)
>       at Object. (angular.js:16730)
>       at r.$digest (angular.js:18747)
>       at r.$apply (angular.js:19054)
>       at g (angular.js:13192)
>       at T (angular.js:14196)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:14364)

Here's a look into the code about what i have been trying to each:

***messageSelectionCtrl.js:***

```
//getMessageSelectionConfigs is the service used to make http request and the successhandler and errorhandler defined in controller.
app.controller('messageSelectionCtrl',['$scope','getMessageSelectionConfigs', 'filterData', '$log','errorService', function($scope, getMessageSelectionConfigs, filterData, $log, errorService){

    $scope.filterData =  filterData;
    ....
    ...

    //service call to fetch message selection config 
    getMessageSelectionConfigs.get(data).then(messageSelectionSuccessHandler,messageSelectionErrorHandler);

    ......
}]);

.......
.....

app.filter('filterByLocale', function(){
  return function (messageSelectionList, locale){
     var filtered = [];
     for (var i=0; i<messageSelectionList.length; i++){
         var item= messageSelectionList[i];
         if(item.locale === locale){
           filtered.push(item);
         }
     }
     return filtered;
  };
});

.....
..
```

***messageSelectionTemplate.html***

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in messageSelectionList | filterByLocale: filterData.locale">
```

***mainCtrl.js***

```
app.factory('filterData', function(){
  return {
    locale : ''
  };
});
```

the `messageSelectionSuccessHandler` function executes after the error comes. This is weird because view should be triggered once ng-repeat has some model to loop in. 
Please let me know what i am missing or any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise messageSelectionList = [] first so its never undefined. The loop will update with data once fetched.

And to ignore empty filters -

```
app.filter('filterByLocale', function(){
  return function (messageSelectionList, locale){
    if(locale){
      var filtered = [];
      for (var i=0; i<messageSelectionList.length; i++){
      var item= messageSelectionList[i];
      if(item.locale === locale){
         filtered.push(item);
       }
     return filtered;
    }
    return messageSelectionList
  }
  };
});
```

Comment: umm..Doing that removes the error which is fine, but nothing got populated in the view. Is it because the filter parameter is initialized with empty string ? Debugging suggests that `filterByLocale` returns empty array. What i want is to have the list rendered first, and when locale changes, view should change again.

Comment: Maybe put a if(filter) round your filter code and ignore empty filters and return the unaltered data

Comment: Yup, that worked like a charm. Appreciate the effort to find issue and helping out.